# adjust time zone

Tags: php, datetime, date

How would I take a stored date, like 2011-01-30 18:23:49, and adjust it to any chosen timezone? Is there a simple way such as simply defining the time zone by abbreviation or adding/subtracting x amount of hours?
Basically I want users to be able to choose their time zone and this default date be adjusted to fit theirs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adjusting time zone in PHP with DateTime / DateTimeZone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445087/adjusting-time-zone-in-php-with-datetime-datetimezone)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Have the user choose their time zone
2. Use that zone name or offset with [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) to set the default time zone used in date functions throughout the rest of script execution.
3. Use [`date('Z')`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to get that time zone's offset from GMT in seconds
4. Convert your stored date to a timestamp with [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) -- UNIX timestamps are always GMT, so you now have the time in GMT.
5. Add the offset from step 3 to convert that time to the user's time zone.
6. Use `date` again to format the timestamp as a string in the desired display format.

Example:

```
$user_timezone = 'America/Los_Angeles';
$stored_time = '2011-01-30 18:23:49';

date_default_timezone_set($user_timezone);
$timestamp = strtotime($stored_time);
$local_timestamp = $timestamp + date('Z');
$local_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $local_timestamp);

echo $local_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here comes my solution. I tested it with America/Los_Angeles as the servers timezone, and my timezone as the users. I assume that the time is stored using the servers timezone.

```
<?php
// My (user) timezone
$user_timezone = 'Europe/Berlin';

// Server timezone
$stored_timezone = 'America/Los_Angeles';

// Date/Time stored in your DB, using timezone of the server (yours, that is)
$stored_datetime = '2011-01-29 22:40:00'; // this is the current time in L.A.

// Setting default to servers timezone if not done before
date_default_timezone_set($stored_timezone);

// converting to unix timestamp
$stored_timestamp = strtotime($stored_datetime);

// setting default to users timezone
date_default_timezone_set($user_timezone);

// converting to timestamp
$user_datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $stored_timestamp);

// setting default back to servers timezone
date_default_timezone_set($stored_timezone);

echo $user_datetime; // output is my current time
```