# Converting a user selected PHP date difference in multiple time zones

Tags: php, utc

I have an auction site where a user can select a date (day and time) from a calendar and drop down (for time). The dates visible are based on the users time zone UTC -10:00 for example. This date can only be in the future to where the server is which is UTC +10:00 and is used to schedule the active date/time of a listing. THe user can select a duration for the active listing also but lets say 7 days for this example.

The users UTC could be anything and say they select 7 days in their future, not 7 days to the servers future. So if I am in a -12:00 then the date is 23 hours yesterday to where the server is.

How can I work out that the selected 7 days in the users future will actually be 7 days to the server future? The date/time will always be displayed in AEST (+10:00).

So basically their 7 days will be 7 days in AEST regardless of the time zone the user is in.

I hope that makes sense.
Cheers!

Comment: Are you using a framework already? If so, probably you should start by finding out if your framework offers date handling.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445087/adjusting-time-zone-in-php-with-datetime-datetimezone)

Comment: Nope. No framework. I will look at the link

Comment: Thanks. The link has the solution to my issue.